# Does it make sense by saying 'upon facing......'

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers, adverbial-phrases

The sentence I wish to write is

> Upon facing difficulties, I will work hard.

Does this sentence make sense? Am I using 'upon' correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems fine to me. I've certainly used 'upon' in a similar context.

Comment: Please include an explanation of *why* this usage is correct.